# How can I align the data label on bar chart (highchart) while exporting as on jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, phantomjs

I have prepared a bar chart on jsfiddle, with the data labels on the chart aligned to left. The same chart I implemented on grails and made an image of it to export. The image is created using PHANTOM JS. The chart is fine on the application but the image formed to export isn't right. While exporting, the data labels on the image are not aligned.

`jsfiddle link to form the chart:`http://jsfiddle.net/d3rfnssq/

Comment: In Safari on Mac it works fine. In chrome and Firefox, when exporting the chart, the labels are printed double.

Comment: This is known bug in Highcharts, reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3649).